# How to enable Windows 7 recovery after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, data-recovery, asus

I bought a Asus K series laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium. I removed Windows and installed Ubuntu.

I left the recovery partition untouched and Ubuntu created an entry in GRUB named `Windows Recovery Environment (loader)`. When I boot into this, Windows 7 logo appears and then a screen with Asus logo appears but the laptop reboots automatically without displaying the recovery options window.

In the default setup, `F9` loaded the recovery screen but now that doesn't work either. What should I do to recover the factory setup of Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out accidentally. Hitting just `F9` or booting into the `Windows Recovery Environment` grub option doesn't work. Only a combination of both works!

`F9` must be hit before grub loads and then the `Windows Recovery Environment` must be chosen for boot in grub.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you removed Windows, it may not be possible. Many laptops ship with a recovery partition, which holds all the information required to rebuild the initial setup.

When you ran your Ubuntu install, did you let it use the entire drive, or did you limit it to the partition that Windows used to be in? If it used the entire drive, you're recovery is hosed, I'm afraid.

You may be able to speak to the shop that provided the laptop and ask for the OEM install media (you normally create this yourself when you first receive a new Windows laptop) - I think they should provide it, but in many areas they don't.

Comment: Like I said in the question, I left the recovery partition untouched. It is still available and the recovery version of Windows is loading up to some point and then does nothing!

Comment: Explain 'some part' - what is it doing? Is it at a prompt?

Comment: I've explained it in the question. `When I boot into this, Windows 7 logo appears and then a screen with Asus logo appears but the laptop reboots automatically without displaying the recovery options window.`